# Disable Android/iOS Keyboard on specific Input Fields

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I would like to disable or hide the Keyboard on Android and iOS on specific Input fields.

is this possible? something like

```
<input type="text" name="date" keyboard="disable" />
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? How is the user supposed to interact with that form field if there's no keyboard?

Comment: I use plugins like date-picker, so I don't see the use of the keyboard

Comment: You are almost there. you can **disable** the input field `<input type="text" name="date" disable/>` and the keyboard will not show up.

Comment: This however disables the plugin aswell

Comment: is the plugin native based or HTML/JS based? If it is HTML/JS based than you need to attach the date-picker widget to the input field as a tooltip that will show on click/touch to the input field. You can have a look over here as to how it is done in Dojo toolkit over [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mobile/DatePicker.html) and [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mobile/DatePicker.html). Assuming it is something similar that you are trying to do.

Comment: Another link where you can directly test the widget in your mobile browser. Link over [here](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/mobile/tests/test_DatePicker.html) and [here](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/mobile/tests/test_DatePicker2.html). The link will work in the desktop browser too, but you will not get a feel of it as compared to a mobile browser

Comment: @frank: ok thanks for the info, I will look up into it.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
$('#input').focus(function() {
  this.blur();
});
```

Comment: If I use this in date picker, it is causing the datepicker popuo to get blured as well.